# AJAX and file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, filereader

I've done a bunch of googling to get to where I am but the last little bit seems to elude me.  Anybody know why the reader.result data is blank? I've played around with different scenarios and sometimes the ajax post doesn't include the reader.result (that code is not present here because I've moved on). I'm thinking I need to stringify it once I get the actual reader.result to be passable to my own variable outside the scope of the reader.onload function.

```
<form id="UploadForm"><input id="FileUpload" type="file"></form>

$('#FileUpload').on("change",function(e) {
var data = {};
var StepID = $(this).data("StepID");
var Step = $(".InstructionPhotos[data-id=" + StepID + "]");
var reader = new FileReader();
var s;

reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("<img class='image uploading' src='" + e.target.result + "'>").appendTo($("#Slides"));
        s = e.target.result;

}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

console.log( reader.result ); //This is blank
console.log (s); //This is undefined

data['RecipeID'] = RecipeID;
data['File'] = $(".uploading").attr("src");
data['Filename'] = e.target.files[0].name;
data['StepID' ] = $(this).data("StepID");
data['page'] = 'recipe_editor';
data['ajax'] = true;

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "index.php",
     data: data,
     dataType: "json"
});
});
```

Comment: Your code isn't showing `result` being passed into the ajax post. But I suspect the issue you're experiencing is that you're making the AJAX call before `reader.result` has completed reading the file. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result):

> This property is only valid after the read operation is complete,

You're reading it immediately after calling `readAsDataURL`. You aren't waiting for the `load` event to fire.

Comment: Thanks! I moved my AJAX request inside the onload function and it worked.